# Convert boost serialization text archive to structured format

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Given

- a boost serialization text archive
- the boost version and the c++ toolset used for serialization

but lacking the data structures the text archive is based on. Is there a way to recover any kind of more readable structured representation (e.g. XML or JSON)?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of the contents of the text archive and what output you'd expect in the XML/JSON?

Comment: I am looking for a general solution. E.g. to converting the text archive output to the equivalent xml archive output without knowing the data structures that produced the former.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not such a way.

Boost Serialization is extensible.

Users can provide their own - pluggable - archive formats. These can encode things like runtime type information in any way they prefer.

Therefore archive implementations cannot know about their implementations, and no conversion can be done except by deserializing and serializing again, using the other archive format.

(More formally: language information is selectively lost on serialization, other archive formats might rely on bits of information not present in the source archive format).

Example: XML archives need tag names which are inherently uninteresting to binary archives. These names cannot possibly be "recovered" from a binary archive because they were never there.